# How do I use Qt to display custom video stream?

Tags: qt, video, qt4

I am a Qt newbie and I am trying to create an application that accepts a stream of raw pixel data that comes in blocks of pixels that I need to consolidate and then render as a video on the screen. Basically 'n' blocks will make up full image to display then as a new block arrives, the existing displayed image needs to be scrolled and the new block inserted. I was thinking of using a `QGraphicsScene` and have each of the blocks placed as objects on the scene. Then move the objects to the left and place the new one on the right, freeing the one that scrolls off the visible area.

Will this work?

I am using this approach since I could not find how to scroll a pixmap image and then fill in only the vacated rectangle with new data.

Is there a better way to display this video stream? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think dividing a video frame into multiple blocks is a good idea. It may cause the video tearing or some other side-effect.
2. Usually, you can transfer the raw pixel data into opengl texture(glTextImage2D), and then render it easily, and you don't have to worry about the block scrolling.
   For better performance, you may refer to FBO/PBO with OpenGL.

Use following References:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html